# How do I limit the number of characters in a wildcard match in a preg_match pattern?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

In the following snippet pre_match returns the first latitude reading followed by a great many characters then the longitude reading.
What I am after is the final latitude/longitude pair.
How do I limit the space between the two readings to a maximum of say 4 characters?
The `.*?` expression allows too many characters.
How might I change this to allow a smaller number?

```
<?php
$lcline="tuesday, 20th. light airs and clear weather. p.m. started at latitude 24 degrees 12 minutes took several azimuth, which gave the variation 16 degrees 30 minutes west. put the ship's company to three watches. wind variable; course south 21 degrees 30 minutes west; distance 28 miles; latitude 31 degrees 17 minutes, longitude 17 degrees 19 minutes west; at noon, funchall, island of madeira, north 13 degrees east, 76 miles. ";

preg_match('/(latitude\s+\d+\s+degrees\s+\d+\s+minutes.*?longitude\s+\d+\s+degrees\s+\d+\s+minutes)/', $lcline, $results);
echo "results=".$results[0]."<BR><BR>"
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Expression
>
> Function
>
> {n}
>
> Match exactly n times, example:Click to test "\w{2}" equals "\w\w";
>   Click to test "a{5}" equals "aaaaa"
>
> {m,n}
>
> At least m but no more than n times: Click to test "ba{1,3}" matches
>   "ba","baa","baaa"
>
> {m,}
>
> Match at least n times: Click to test "\w\d{2,}" matches
>   "a12","_456","M12344"...
>
> ?
>
> Match 1 or 0 times, equivalent to {0,1}: Click to test "a[cd]?"
>   matches "a","ac","ad".
>
> - Match 1 or more times, equivalent to {1,}: Click to test "a+b" matches
>     "ab","aab","aaab"...
> - 
>
> Match 0 or more times, equivalent to {0,}: Click to test "\^*b"
>   matches "b","^^^b"...

Reference : http://www.regexlab.com/en/regref.htm

Comment: this solves it. changing   .*?  to  .{1,4} limits the gap between the latitude and longitude readings

Comment: however when i loop through a text file of captain cook's log, extracting lines one at a time,  i cannot get this preg_match to find any matches in each line at all -- though there are hundreds!

Answer (score 1):

Add `.+` at the begining of the regex and get the result from group 1:

```
preg_match('/.+(latitude\s+\d+\s+degrees\s+\d+\s+minutes.*?longitude\s+\d+\s+degrees\s+\d+\s+minutes)/s', $lcline, $results);
echo "results=",$results[1],"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
results=latitude 31 degrees 17 minutes, longitude 17 degrees 19 minutes
```

Answer (score 0):

If u say limit, you can use **curly braces**
eg:  `/\s{4}/` this will select all with 4 white space characters consecutively

Comment: This answer is close to a solution but it doesn't answer how to find a varying number of random characters between the entries